# Finding files on a Unix server and sorting by size

Tags: find, sort, size

I have a web server where I have run out of space and it's causing issues with the [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) sites I am running on them.

I know that I have a lot of large .png files (the fact that it's [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) is a mistake in itself, but let's not get into that).

I would like to get the list of PNG or [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) files that are on the server and sort them by decreasing size. I know I can use `ls -SlahR`, but the sorting is on a per-folder basis.

I then came up with `find . -name "*.png" | xargs -i -n1 ls -lah {}` which is OK except that (a) it doesn't sort the lines and (b) it shows the file permissions and ownerships which I couldn't care less about.

So is there something better? Something that would produce [size] [path_to_file]?

Comment: Is this really UNIX or do you mean Linux? Do you have access to the GNU versions of the classic tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a combination of `find`, `du` and `sort` like the following:

```
find <directory> -iname "*.png" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 du -b | sort -n -r
```

This searches for all regular files in `<directory>` ending with `.png` (case-insensitive). The result is then passed to `xargs` which calls `du` with each single file, getting its size in bytes (due to `-b`) and passed to `sort`, which sorts the result numerically (`-n`) by the file size in decreasing order (`-r`). The `-print0` is used to separate the results by `\0` instead of `\n`, so you can have paths with strange characters like spaces and newlines.

Answer (score 10):

You can just do the whole thing with (GNU) `find` and `sort`, no need for `du`:

```
$ find . -iname '*png' -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -rn
68109 ./7.png
21751 ./2.png
21751 ./1.png
5393 ./6.png
2542 ./5.png
1717 ./4.png
1003 ./3.png
878 ./10.png
793 ./9.png
587 ./8.png
```

Comment: Not every `find` has `-printf` (e.g. NetBSD's `find` in the base system). `find ...|stat ...|sort ...` can help then...

Comment: @yeti I know, that's why [I asked the OP](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157904/finding-files-on-a-unix-server-and-sorting-by-size/157906?noredirect=1#comment258574_157904) to clarify if they have access to the GNU tools.

Answer (score 2):

And just in case you need to have the most compatible version, you can do it with regular find and sort (no reliance on gnu extensions, such as printf):

`find . -ls | grep -i -e '\.png$' -e '\.jpe*g' | sort -k7,7nr`

`-k7,7` : Sort on columns `7 to 7` (ie, only 7)
  (... this should be a parameter, allowing one to change the column number in case on their old system find -ls output sizes in bytes on a different column)